# Jenkins shared library and jenkinsFiles at the same repo

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries

Is it possible to have a global shared library and jenkinsFiles at the same repo?

I want to have something like

```
─ root
   ├── all-jenkins-files
   |    └── dir1
   |        └── Jenkinsfile1
   |    └── dir2
   |        └── Jenkinsfile2
   ├── shared-libraries
       └── src
       └── var
```

I was trying to use globel shared libraries configuration but I believe it failed because of the directories structure. global shared-libraries expecting to have `src` and `var`
folders under root dir.

any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: It is possible but little differently, instead of keeping pipelines under root, you could have them inside the `shared-libraries` directory it self say for example under `pipeline_files`. So the final structure will look like,
```
test_sharedlib/
├── pipeline_files
│   └── Jenkinsfile
├── src
│   └── com
│       └── org
│           └── devops
│               └── test.txt
└── vars
    ├── SayHi.groovy 
```
I do not think there is other way round since shared lib is only valid when it contains `vars` and `src` dir structure

Answer (score 1):

Yes It's possible to have a shared library like structure in the same folder, but I don't think you can use like a shared library (implicit or dynamic loading).

With this kind of scenario, you can make use of `load` DSL.

If the folder in SCM like :

```
.
├── shared-library
│   ├── src
│   └── vars
│       ├── log.groovy
│       ├── myPipeline.groovy
│  
├── all-jenkins-file
│   └── Jenkinsfile
```

**shared-library/vars/myPipeline.groovy**

```
stage('01') {
    echo "01"
}
stage('02') {
    echo "02"
}
stage('03') {
    echo "03"
}
```

**shared-library/vars/log.groovy**

```
def info(message) {
    echo "INFO: ${message}"
}

def warning(message) {
    echo "WARNING: ${message}"
}
return this;
```

**all-jenkins-file/Jenkinsfile**

```
node {
    checkout scm
    load "${env.WORKSPACE}/shared-library/vars/myPipeline.groovy"

    def log =load "${env.WORKSPACE}/shared-library/vars/log.groovy"
    log.info('Hello')
    
}
```